# WooCommerce Address error (C# UWP)

Tags: c#, wordpress, visual-studio, woocommerce, uwp

I try to receive data from WC like this

```
RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://simplegames.com.ua/wp-json/wc/v1/", "ck_9d64c027d2c5f81b8bed3342eeccc6d337be813d", "cs_60697b1e6cbdeb8d62d19e0765e339f8e3334754");

WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
//Get all products
var orders = await wc.GetOrders();


foreach (var order in orders) {
    Debug.WriteLine($"Currency: {order.currency},Date:{order.date_created},Adress: {order.shipping},  Total Cost: {order.total}");
}
```

In this code all okay.

But I have this in output `Adress: WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.ShippingAddress`

Why I don't see address?

Comment: Can you show the code for your `WCObject` class please?

Comment: I use WooCommerce.NET plugin

https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET


This one @JayGould

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `Console.WriteLine($"{order.shipping}");` is printing an instance of `shipping` property, instead of the `value of the field`. Without going through the source of the plugin, something similar to `order.shipping.streetname, order.shipping.town` may be the solution.